# Multiple email ids in single text field - how to send each an email?

Tags: visualforce

I have multiple email ids (comma separated) in single field. I need to read those email ids and send them an email of predefined format together with a link to a client unique in each email. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: send emails how? via process builder/workflow? or via apex outbound email?

Comment: in workflow can u explain please

Answer (score 1):

There's just no way to do it with Workflow because they either accept hard-coded emails in the Workflow definition itself or specific email fields. If it's absolutely necessary to have a text field contain multiple email addresses, you would have to use Apex Messaging.SingleEmailMessage and separate the addresses at the comma before adding them as recipients.

If I had to do this declaratively, I would create a custom child object to which each email address is added as an Email field on a separate record and have the workflow run off that object. Or create multiple email address fields on the original object that the Workflow Rule can use. Both of those designs are really poor choices and exactly the kind of problems that Apex was introduced to solve.

Comment: n.b. there is a daily limit of outbound apex emails that might interfere with your suggestion depending on OP's org